# htaccess rewrite rule to remove parameters from URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The user types the following into the browser and this remains the url in the browser:
xyz.com/info/productname/

Internally this becomes:
xyz.com/info/index.php?product=productname

The following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/?$ /info/index.php?product=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Is really close.  Unfortunately the problem seems to be that the relative file links don't work when using xyz.com/info/productname/

See the difference between:

http://xyz.com/info/swoosh
and
http://xyz.com/info/swoosh/

The second one doesn't work because relative links are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Take out leading slash from regex
- Take out R=302
- Add QSA
- Make sure request is not for a file.directory

Modified rule:

```
# fix relative links of css, js, images
RewriteRule ^info/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/.]+)/?$ /info/index.php?product=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```